Problem with widehat command in lualatex
I have a problem with the widehat command in lualatex.
I have loaded the lualatex-math package that fixes some of the
problems. Here is MWE.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\usepackage[notext,sans]{kpfonts-otf}
\setmathfont{Kp Math SansBold}[Scale=1.1,range=bfup/{num,Latin,latin}]
\usepackage{lualatex-math}
\begin{document}
    This is a test.\\
    \[\mathrm{This\ is\ a\ test.}\]
    \[\mathbf{\widehat{u}}\]
    \[\widehat{\mathbf{u}}\]
        \[\symbf{\widehat{u}}\]
    \[\widehat{\symbf{u}}\]
    \[\widehat{\symrm{u}}\]
\end{document}

As one can see from the image below, the hat is not placed properly and it is small. It works fine with Kp-fonts. However, the font is not close to Arial. So, I need a Sansserif font that looks very similar to Arial and in which \widehat command works.

EDIT I have removed the unnecessary commands. I still have to load tex-gyre-pagella and change the mathematics font afterwards.  Otherwise unicode-maths gives an error message.

You are messing a lot with fonts, in particular seems to use a non-math font for some alphabets (if I understand the code correctly). Usually these characters come with an anchor point, but for a non-math font like Arial I would not suppose they do. In my opinion what you do is asking for trouble.

You're probably facing a similar problem to me (aka using text font for the letters and numbers in math, I'm looking for a solution too), see in the log, it complains about not being able to find suitable math sections in Arial. I'm assuming that it is why it does not know how to properly place the hat.

@mickep given the low numbers of suitable math fonts, there really ought to be some solution for this. I'm looking for one as well. Not sure if the hackery from mathastext can be used here.

If you try the methods from mathastext it also seems to place things like \tilde wrong. Plus the interletter spacing is wrong. Though mathastext then also seems to be redefining \tilde etc afterwards to work.

This issue is lualatex related.  There is a file lualatex-math.sty that fixes some of the other problems like the \binom command.  But this hasn't been fixed. @mickep 1, yes, I need to use Arial for the text in Mathematics also.  I don't think that problem is because of this.

I think this could help. With the unicode-math package, \math... commands use the text font (Arial), \symb... commands the math font (Kp Fonts). You use Arial for the letter u but Kp Fonts for \widehat, this explains the discrepancy. Use only \symb... commands or find a more compatible math font (try GFSNeohellenicMath.otf for example). Anyway, there is no Arial math font.

@jlab The \unicode-mathpackage is already loaded by kpfonts-otf.

Both  KpMath-Sans.otf  and GFSNeohellenicMath.otf look too thin to match Arial, I would give a try to LatoMath.otf. This will not solve your \widehat issue, but as already said by other contributors, \mathrmand \mathbf print text font which require anchors to position the accents. \widehat is a math accent not understanding  anchors.
